# DB select with java util date

Tags: java, sql, date

The DB persist `java.util.date` and i need a query to get all the data between 2 Dates with only using `java.util.date.`
I use the `JPA 2.1`

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE created > '"+date1+"' AND created < '"+date2+"'";
```

This query provides always a List with 0 elements

Comment: Can you try: Query q = em.createQuery("Select m from table m "      + "where m.created > :date1 and m.created < :date2"); q.setParameter("date1", date1);  q.setParameter("date2", date2);  List<Message> results = (List<Message>) q.getResultList();

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your dates are being added to the SQL query as string values. The database is getting something like:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE created > 'Wed May 25 14:33:18 SAST 2016' and created < 'Wed May 25 14:33:18 SAST 2016'";
```

The database is seeing it as a string and that explains why it isn't working.

The single best way to resolve it is use bind variables::

```
String sql = ""SELECT * FROM table WHERE created > ? AND created < ?"
//Create the query object using that SQL string, then set values
sqlQuery.setParameter(1, date1);
sqlQuery.setParameter(2, date2);
```

Then [execute the prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).